# Please explain if golang types pass by value

Tags: go, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, pass-by-pointer

I'm trying to make a very simple program that modifies arrays, but ran across some interesting behavior if I converted them to types. https://play.golang.org/p/KC7mqmHuLw It appears that if I have an array go passes by reference, but if I have a type then go passes by value.  Is this correct?

I have two variables b and c, both are arrays of 3 integers, but c is of type cT, in every other respect they should be identical.  I can assign values as `b[0]=-1` and `c[0]=-1`, but if I pass those arrays as parameters to a function they act very differently.

The output of the program is:

> before b: [1 2 3]
>
> before c: [1 2 3]
>
> *after b: [-1 2 0]
>
> *after c: [-1 2 3]
>
> *what? c: [-1 2 0]

My initial assumption is that the lines "after b" and "after c" should have been the same.  Am I doing something incorrectly or am I correct about types passing to functions by value (ie. creating copy of the variable before passing to the function)?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type cT [3]int

func main() {
    b := []int{1, 2, 3}
    c := cT{1, 2, 3}

    fmt.Println("before b:", b)
    fmt.Println("before c:", c)

    b[0] = -1
    c[0] = -1
    mangleB(b) // ignore return value
    mangleC(c) // ignore return value

    fmt.Println("*after b:", b)
    fmt.Println("*after c:", c)

    c = mangleC(c)    
    fmt.Println("*what? c:", c)    
}

func mangleB(row []int) []int {
    row[2] = 0
    return row
}

func mangleC(row cT) cT{
    row[2] = 0
    return row
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the help!  With the information provided, I am getting the effect I want by passing a reference to the type `manglePC(&c)` and changing the function to: `func manglePC(row *cT) {
 (*row)[2] = 0
}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Array types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Array_types)
>
> An array is a numbered sequence of elements of a single type, called
>   the element type.
>
> [Slice types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types)
>
> A slice is a descriptor for a contiguous segment of an underlying
>   array and provides access to a numbered sequence of elements from that
>   array.
>
> [Calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)
>
> In a function call, the function value and arguments are evaluated in
>   the usual order. After they are evaluated, the parameters of the call
>   are passed by value to the function and the called function begins
>   execution. The return parameters of the function are passed by value
>   back to the calling function when the function returns.

---

> ```
> type cT [3]int
>
> b := []int{1, 2, 3}
> c := cT{1, 2, 3}
> ```
>
> I have two variables, `b` and `c`, both are arrays of 3 integers

---

No, you don't!

`b` is a **slice** of `int` with length (`len(b)`) 3 and capacity (`cap(b)`) 3, `c` is an **array** of (`len(c)`) 3 `int`.

In Go, all parameters are passed by value. `b` is passed as a slice descriptor, `c` is passed as an array. A slice descriptor is a `struct` with a slice length and capacity, and a pointer to the underlying array.

Comment: Isn't a slice descriptor a reference, meaning passing a slice descriptor is passing a reference?

Answer (score 0):

See comments:

```golang
func main() {
    b := []int{1, 2, 3} // slice
    c := cT{1, 2, 3} // array

    fmt.Println("before b:", b) 
    fmt.Println("before c:", c) 

    b[0] = -1
    c[0] = -1

    // passing in a slice which you can think of as ref to array
    // pass by value, and it is copy of ref to array 
    mangleB(b) // ignore return value

    // passing in copy of array (pass by value)
    // yes full shallow copy of array 
    mangleC(c) // ignore return value
    // if you ignore return modifications are lost

    fmt.Println("*after b:", b)
    fmt.Println("*after c:", c)

    // return value is modified array
    c = mangleC(c)
    // c now copy of array from line 24

    fmt.Println("*what? c:", c)
}
```

- when I'm calling slice a ref I'm simplifying details here https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

https://play.golang.org/p/OAaCMhc-Ug